# GeoJson Layer not showing on browser, but working on RStudio Viewer

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard, r-leaflet

I have a Shiny App made with leaflet. I need to show a map, and then plot some lines from geojson files on top. **This works *perfectly* on the RStudio Viewer, but the geojson lines are *not showing* on the browser**.

I have checked this: it is not the browser (tried 3, and it never works), it is not the layout, not the R version, not the operative system (tried running on Windows and Linux). I tried manually adding style to the lines, and to remove the loading from the `observe({...})` chunk, but it still does not work on any browser.

EDIT: I have also tried to remove `setVIew(...)` and `setMaxBounds(...)` alternately, and the geojson lines still do not appear on the browser.

I made a reprex for my app:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(jsonlite)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel(""),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        leafletOutput("map", width="100%", height="600px")
      )
   )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  gj <- readRDS("gj.rds")


  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      # Set the view
      setView(-60.704, -63.229, zoom = 13) %>%
      # Restrict the map to only show the city bounds
      setMaxBounds(-60.757, -31.556, -60.651, -31.673)
  })


  # Show the basic lines here
  observe({
    leafletProxy("map") %>% addGeoJSON(toJSON(gj), layerId = "lines")

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The dataset with the lines is huge, so I'm uploading a reduced version here. However, it is too big and I cant put a `dput` over here either. Please, download the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ib5yr2IsuGoTmOuzeyhvIe-vjXILdEnD

EDIT: The code shared here is the bare minimum used to run a basic shinyapp and test the issue. There is no additional information.

Comment: Instead of us downloading an unknown file from a third-party service, could you just use a shapefile commonly available, like from a mapping-related package?

Comment: I'd also recommend commenting out any code that isn't immediately necessary for the sake of debugging. Strip it down to just its essence and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: @camille the code I uploaded is the bare minimum to run the app, see the map, and the geojson file. I'm changing the link to my own Google Drive.

Comment: What I mean is that I'd check for the off-chance that maybe `setView`, the sizing attributes in your `leafletOutput`, etc could be rendering differently in the browsers from what you expect.

Comment: @camille But the map renders correctly in the browser. Only the geojson does not render.

Comment: I'm getting what seems to be the same output in RStudio as in Firefox. But I know a lot of other folks won't want to download a file from a third party, which is why I suggested using a shapefile that's available some other way

Comment: @camille so you see the lines plotted in firefox? Which version are you using, and can you share a screenshot? I'm not using a shapefile because I suspected it could be from my own data. I can cut it to a cuple of rows to be able to use a  `dput` though.